# What is the recommended interval change a Holden Barina timing belt?

Tags: timing-belt, service

It's a 2009 Holden Barina TK with 44,000 km on the clock. The mechanic is recommending that it's time to change the timing belt, but it seems to soon to me for such a costly procedure.

When I've had them changed in other cars it's been closer to the 150k service.

Comment: Your mechanic is trying to get you to get you to do maintenance you don't need. Just tell him "No" and get it done at the proper maintenance interval. Like you said, it's expensive enough. No need to make it even more expensive. Besides, if anything *were* to happen (which I doubt would) between your current mileage and what is recommended, your warranty will cover it. Another old saying which may apply here is ... *If it ain't broke, don't fix it.* ... I'd modify it a bit to say, *If it isn't worn out, don't replace it.*

Comment: I would add to @Paulster2 answer and tell you to find another shop, never  go back there as the technician cannot be trusted.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that car specifically, but in general, Holdens have their timing belt (**and** waterpump) replaced every 75000km to 120000km.

But open your car's service booklet. It should tell you the service schedules and what you need to do at each interval. Usually all of them will suggest at least inspecting belts for wear. Keep in mind that a broken timing belt will cause major engine damage, usually in the form of bent valves and pistons.

Comment: It appears to be 4 years/60,000km. Oh well.

Comment: Strange. I just checked wikipedia and your Barina is sold in South Africa as the Opel Corsa D. I have a Corsa B and its interval is 90 000km and the D model has the exact same engine, except for having a more efficient header. Oh well, do what the book says. The parts for these cars are cheap enough.

Comment: @JuannStrauss ... Not only are the parts cheap, but the alternative (as you describe) is fairly costly.

Comment: For reference: the South African price for an OEM timing belt kit is the equivalent of about 60 to 80 AUD. That doesn't include labour, but labour should be about 2 to 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

My 2006 TK (bought new) has 205,000 Ks, runs beautifully, never been to a shop only serviced by me , best oils and filters at short intervals, no timing belt change yet, and not until 250,000Ks and then again at 500,000Ks.

Answer (score 0):

My original was a '95  Barina & it was in the book at 60,000kms. My personal mechanic said he'd change it as I'd already bought the 'Holden' timing belt. He did say it was far too early as he changes most brands more in the 130,000km mark with non-genuine belts & suggested about another 30% on top of that as a safety margin ... my next one, a '99 SB, the book said 120,000kms which is what I now work from ... A BLOODY BIG DIFFERENCE !

Answer (score 0):

You must pay attention to the *time* interval as well as the *distance* interval, and change the belt at the first of them to occur. If (as you say in your comment) the change requirement is 4 years or 60K km, then the belt is already overdue for changing.